# PySpark pass list to User Defined Function

Tags: list, dataframe, pyspark, bigdata, user-defined-functions

I have a DataFrame with one column. In each row of this column, there is a list that has a different number of integers. For example row 1 has a list with 5 integers. Row 2 has a list with 8 integers and ...
I want to write a UDF that gets each row as a list and multiply all the integers in the list and return the result as a number.
I want to have the answers in another column so it would be df.withColumn(...)
**For some reason, I do want to use UDF** and NOT any other pre-built function or command. 
Thank you for your time and support.

Answer (score 1):

Defining some sample input data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, [3, 4, 8]), (2, [7, 2, 6, 8])
], ("id", "list_of_ints"))

df.show()
```

Definition of `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
def product(numbers):
     a = 1
     for num in numbers:
         a *= num
     return a

from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
product_udf = udf(lambda z: product(z), IntegerType())
```

And adding a column with a product of all the list elements:

```
df.withColumn("product", product_udf("list_of_ints")).show()

+---+------------+-------+
| id|list_of_ints|product|
+---+------------+-------+
|  1|   [3, 4, 8]|     96|
|  2|[7, 2, 6, 8]|    672|
+---+------------+-------+
```

Hope this helps!